# Azure Management Libraries Resource Re-Creation

Tags: azure, azure-sdk

What actually happens within Azure when I create a resource with Azure Management Libraries, and then recreate the same exact resource? Does it "see" that the same exact resource is there and doesn't do anything? Or does it wipe out the existing resource and create a new, exact same one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a resource within azure, then you try to use Management Libraries to create the same exact resource. The library will first check it's name availability, if the name is in used(which means it's not available), then it will return false(an error will throw in your code) to indicate you cannot create this resource.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. This helps a lot.